# Dataset description AREA_OR_POINT

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, remote-sensing, imagery, file-formats

What are the differences between these two options in satellite image  metadata?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your data provider really but https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc33_gtiff_pixelispoint has a nice note about the options in general:

> RasterPixelIsArea defines that a pixel represents an area in the real
>   world, while RasterPixelIsPoint defines a pixel to represent a point
>   in the real world. Often this is useful to distinguish the behavior of
>   optical sensors that average light values over an area vs. raster data
>   which is point oriented like an elevation sample at a point.